# Can't ping/SSH into brand new Cisco Cat4510 switches

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst

I have copied configs and IOS from known good/in place switches (making obvious changes to VLAN IP's, ports, etc), but cannot ping VLAN1 on the new switch from my laptop though I can from another switch. (the new switch is on the same network as known good switches, same mask, etc.) Is there something in the new switches that disables ICMP and/or SSH?
Additionally, the switch CAN connect to the network via trunk, and pull VTP information, as well as allow end devices (VoIP phones, PC's, etc) to connect and function as desired. The switch seems to function as it should, sans for the fact I cannot remote into it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So were the old switches 4510s or what?  One possibility is that the vlan 1 interface may be shut down - sometimes on some models of switches that is the default.